# c++ mpi segmentation fault on slurm

Tags: c++, boost, mpi

I am running the same boost MPI C++ program on slurm and on my Mac. Both are running with 1 node 16 cores.... However, on my Mac, I never get the segmentation fault error while on SLURM super computing system, I almost always get the segmentation fault if i run on many cores (if I only run on 4 cores, the error does not happen, if on 32 cores, then it almost always happen) (it just seems like the segmentation fault is happening by randomness, each time)

```
[c558-403.stampede.tacc.utexas.edu:mpi_rank_0][error_sighandler] Caught error: Segmentation fault (signal 11)
```

by writing the execution of every line on the screen, I realize seg-fault for main happens at:

```
     mpi_world.recv(dst_rank, 1,spin_tmp);
```

and spin_tmp is:

```
     map<tuple<int,int,int,int>,int>  spin_tmp;
```

where as the tuple is from boost tuple. I am really struggling and have no idea what on earth is happening....

I would like to give a minimal version of code here:

main.cpp

```
int main (void){

    mpi::environment mpi_env;
    mpi::communicator mpi_world;
    if (mpi_world.rank()==0)
    {
        read_from_file(id, max_sites, J, prec, num_loops, translation_algorithm,
                       basic_exact_mode, pseudo_mode, pseudo_mode_with_proof,
                       verbose, very_verbose, obscenely_verbose,input_PRIM_output_PRIMOUT_mode,limit_dimension,constant,mu,mu_translation_algorithm,mu_constant,work_with_mu,scan_chemical_potential,new_cluster_algorithm,use_new_pair_terms,use_new_triplet_terms, output_more_states,output_states_below_hull,how_much_lower,output_states_how_sparse,use_level_method,use_weighted_dual_average,global_parameters);

    }
    else
    {
        bool restart_signal=true;

        periodic_slave();
        return 0;
    }



      corecode(components, x_range, y_range, z_range, max_sites, num_loops,
             Ji,
             lowerboundclustertype, upperboundclustertype, cellrepresentation,
             lower_bound, upper_bound, unitcell, periodicity, J_for_proof,
             id, pseudo_mode, pseudo_mode_with_proof, basic_exact_mode,
             very_verbose, obscenely_verbose,limit_dimension,new_cluster_algorithm,use_new_pair_terms,use_new_triplet_terms,map_periodicity_to_spin,  use_level_method, use_weighted_dual_average,global_parameters);
}
```

in periodic_function.cpp (specifically for slave)

```
void periodic_slave()
{
    mpi::communicator mpi_world;



    cout<<"\n hello I am slave: "<<mpi_world.rank()<<" received the global parameters"<<endl;


    bool kill_all_slave=false;

    broadcast(mpi_world,kill_all_slave,0);

    while (kill_all_slave==false) {


        vector<tuple<int,int,int,int,int,int> > periodicity_vector;

        std::cout << "[SLAVE: " << mpi_world.rank()<< "] I am waiting to receive periodicity vector"<<endl;

        periodicity_vector.clear();

        broadcast(mpi_world,periodicity_vector,0);

        std::cout << "[SLAVE: " << mpi_world.rank()<< "] I am waiting to J "<<endl;

//        J.clear();

        map<set<tuple<int,int,int,int,int> >, double> J;


        broadcast(mpi_world,J,0);

        int x_range,y_range,z_range;
        double min_bound;
        map<int,int> component;

        cout<< "[SLAVE: " << mpi_world.rank()<<"] hello I am slave: "<<mpi_world.rank()<<" received 3rd set of the global parameters"<<endl;

        broadcast(mpi_world,x_range,0);
        broadcast(mpi_world,y_range,0);

        cout<< "[SLAVE: " << mpi_world.rank()<<"] hello I am slave: "<<mpi_world.rank()<<" received 4th set of the global parameters"<<endl;
        broadcast(mpi_world,z_range,0);
        broadcast(mpi_world,component,0);
        cout<< "[SLAVE: " << mpi_world.rank()<<"] hello I am slave: "<<mpi_world.rank()<<" received 5th set of the global parameters"<<endl;


        broadcast(mpi_world,min_bound,0);

        cout<< "[SLAVE: " << mpi_world.rank()<<"] hello I am slave: "<<mpi_world.rank()<<" received 6th set of the global parameters"<<endl;

        bool stop = false;
        string status="initial";
        mpi_world.send(0, 0, status);
//        
        cout<< "[SLAVE: " << mpi_world.rank()<<"] hello I am slave: "<<mpi_world.rank()<<" I am going to send to root status"<<endl;


        mpi_world.recv(0, 0, stop);

        cout<< "[SLAVE: " << mpi_world.rank()<<"] hello I am slave: "<<mpi_world.rank()<<" I am going to receive stop signal from root"<<endl;


        while(!stop) {

            map< tuple<int,int,int,int,int,int>, map<set<tuple<int,int,int,int,int> >, double> > clustertype_periodic;

            // Wait for new job

            unsigned int job_id = 0;

            cout<< "[SLAVE: " << mpi_world.rank()<<"] hello I am slave: "<<mpi_world.rank()<<" I am going to receive job id from root"<<endl;

            mpi_world.recv(0, 0, job_id);

            cout<< "[SLAVE: " << mpi_world.rank()<<"] hello I am slave: "<<mpi_world.rank()<<" I am going to receive stop min bound from root"<<endl;


            mpi_world.recv(0, 1, min_bound);


            std::cout << "[SLAVE: " << mpi_world.rank()

            << "] Received job " << job_id << " from MASTER.\n"<<endl;

            // Perform "job"

            map<tuple<int,int,int,int>,int>  spin_tmp;
            double energy_tmp=0;

            tuple<int,int,int,int,int,int>  periodicity_now;
            {
                int i=job_id;
                periodicity_now=periodicity_vector[i];
                int a0=periodicity_now.get<0>();
                int a1=periodicity_now.get<1>();
                int a2=periodicity_now.get<2>();
                int a3=periodicity_now.get<3>();
                int a4=periodicity_now.get<4>();
                int a5=periodicity_now.get<5>();

                {
                    if (pseudo_mode) {



                        periodic(a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5,
                                 J, x_range, y_range, z_range, component,
                                 spin_tmp,
                                 energy_tmp,
                                 clustertype_periodic, min_bound, id,
                                 true, false, false,
                                 obscenely_verbose,global_parameters);

                        //                    {
                        //                        spin_periodic[make_tuple(a0,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5)]=spin_tmp;
                        //                        energy_periodic[make_tuple(a0,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5)]=energy_tmp;
                        //                    }
                    }
                    else if (basic_exact_mode){




                        periodic(a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5,
                                 J, x_range, y_range, z_range, component,
                                 spin_tmp,
                                 energy_tmp,
                                 clustertype_periodic, min_bound, id,
                                 false, true, false,
                                 obscenely_verbose,global_parameters);

                        //                    {
                        //                        spin_periodic[make_tuple(a0,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5)]=spin_tmp;
                        //                        energy_periodic[make_tuple(a0,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5)]=energy_tmp;
                        //                    }


                    }

                }
            }



            // Notify master that the job is done

            std::cout << "[SLAVE: " << mpi_world.rank()

            << "] Done with job " << job_id << ". Notifying MASTER.\n"<<endl;

            status="finish";

            mpi_world.send(0, 0,status);
//            std::cout << "[SLAVE: " << mpi_world.rank()<< "] I have sent status back to master"<<endl;

            //note here, I deliberated exclude cluster_type_periodic which may be the culprit of a lot of bad computing performance for realistic system

            //send periodicity, spin_tmp and energy_tmp

            //        and remember to send more detail;


            mpi_world.send(0, 1,spin_tmp);
            std::cout << "[SLAVE: " << mpi_world.rank()<< "] I have sent spin_tmp back to master"<<endl;
            mpi_world.send(0, 2,energy_tmp);
            std::cout << "[SLAVE: " << mpi_world.rank()<< "] I have sent energy_tmp back to master"<<endl;
            mpi_world.send(0, 3,periodicity_now);
            std::cout << "[SLAVE: " << mpi_world.rank()<< "] I have sent periodicity_now back to master"<<endl;


            // Check if a new job is coming

            mpi_world.recv(0, 0, stop);
            std::cout << "[SLAVE: " << mpi_world.rank()<< "] I have receive stop from master and stop is "<<stop<<endl;


        }


        std::cout << "[SLAVE: " << mpi_world.rank()<< "] I am waiting for signal whether kill_all_slave"<<endl;


        broadcast(mpi_world,kill_all_slave,0);

        std::cout << "[SLAVE: " << mpi_world.rank()<< "] I receive kill_all_slave signal as "<<kill_all_slave<<endl;


    }



    std::cout << "~~~~~~~~ Rank " << mpi_world.rank() << " is exiting ~~~~~~~~~~~\n"<<endl;




}
```

For solver.cpp (for MASTER)

```
void corecode(map<int, int> component,
              int x_range, int y_range, int z_range,
              int max_sites,
              int loopnumber,
              map<set<tuple<int,int,int,int,int> >, double> &J,
              map<set<tuple<int,int,int,int,int> >, double> &lowerboundclustertype,
              map<set<tuple<int,int,int,int,int> >, double> &upperboundclustertype,
              map<tuple<int,int,int,int>,int> &cellrepresentation,
              double &lower_bound, double &upper_bound,
              map<tuple<int,int,int,int>,int> &unitcell,
              tuple<int,int,int,int,int,int> &periodicity,
              map<set<tuple<int,int,int,int,int> >, double> &J_for_proof,
              std::string id,
              bool pseudo_mode,
              bool pseudo_mode_with_proof,
              bool basic_exact_mode,
              bool very_verbose,
              bool obscenely_verbose,
              double limit_dimension,bool new_cluster_algorithm,int use_new_pair_terms,int use_new_triplet_terms, map<tuple<int,int,int,int,int,int>, map<tuple<int,int,int,int>,int> > &map_periodicity_to_spin, bool use_level_method,bool use_weighted_dual_average ,solver_variable &global_parameters)
{

    mpi::communicator mpi_world;


    cout<<"\n what is global_parameters.dedicated1D: "<<global_parameters.dedicated1D<<" what is  dimension==1:"<<(dimension==1)<<endl;

    if (!(global_parameters.dedicated1D==true&&dimension==1)) {


        // Obtain upper bound estimate on the energy
        if (max_sites > 0){

            vector<tuple<int,int,int,int,int,int> > periodicity_vector;
            periodicity_vector.clear();

            bool done=false;

            cout<<"\n debug 02819374 periodicity_vector.size(): "<<periodicity_vector.size()<<endl;

            bool kill_all_slave=false;
            usleep(100000);
            cout<<"[MASTER] I am broadcasting kill_all_slave"<<endl;

            broadcast(mpi_world,kill_all_slave,0);

            usleep(100000);
            cout<<"[MASTER] I am broadcasting periodicity_vector"<<endl;

            broadcast(mpi_world,periodicity_vector,0);

            usleep(1000000);
            cout<<"[MASTER] I am broadcasting J"<<endl;

            broadcast(mpi_world,J,0);

            usleep(1000000);
            cout<<"[MASTER] I am broadcasting x_range"<<endl;

            broadcast(mpi_world,x_range,0);
            usleep(100000);
            cout<<"[MASTER] I am broadcasting y_range"<<endl;

            broadcast(mpi_world,y_range,0);
            usleep(100000);
            cout<<"[MASTER] I am broadcasting z_range"<<endl;

            broadcast(mpi_world,z_range,0);
            usleep(100000);
            cout<<"[MASTER] I am broadcasting component"<<endl;

            broadcast(mpi_world,component,0);
            usleep(100000);
            cout<<"[MASTER] I am broadcasting minbound"<<endl;

            broadcast(mpi_world,min_bound,0);
            usleep(100000);
            //            lets write something here, for loop starts here:
            set<int> killed_slave;
            map<int, string > status_of_slave;

            // Initialize requests
            unsigned int job_id = 0;
            std::vector<mpi::request> reqs(mpi_world.size());

            //            cout<<"\n hello I am root: I am going to send to receieve status status"<<endl;

            // Send initial jobs
            for (unsigned int dst_rank = 1; dst_rank < mpi_world.size(); ++dst_rank) {

                // Post receive request for new jobs requests by slave [nonblocking]
                cout<<"[MASTER] I am i receving status_of_slave: "<<dst_rank<<endl;

                reqs[dst_rank] = mpi_world.irecv(dst_rank, 0,status_of_slave[dst_rank]);
                ++job_id;
            }

            //            cout<<"\n hello I am root: I finish status request"<<endl;


            // Send jobs as long as there is job left
            while(job_id < periodicity_vector.size()) {
                bool stop;
                for (unsigned int dst_rank = 1; dst_rank < mpi_world.size(); ++dst_rank) {
                    // Check if dst_rank is done
                    //                    cout<<"status_of_slave["<<dst_rank<<"] is "<<status_of_slave[dst_rank] <<endl;
                    if (reqs[dst_rank].test()) {
                        cout<<"[MASTER] I receive reqs[dst_rank].test() is: "<<1<<endl;
                        cout<<"status_of_slave["<<dst_rank<<"] is "<<status_of_slave[dst_rank] <<endl;

                        if(status_of_slave[dst_rank]=="finish") {
                            //note here, I deliberated exclude cluster_type_periodic which may be the culprit of a lot of bad computing performance for realistic system

                            cout<<"[MASTER] I receive finish status "<<endl;

                            //                            remember to receive more detail output;
                            //                            and update the things you want to update;
                            map<tuple<int,int,int,int>,int>  spin_tmp;
                            double energy_tmp=0;
                            mpi_world.recv(dst_rank, 1,spin_tmp);
                            cout<<"[MASTER] I receive spin_tmp status "<<endl;

                            mpi_world.recv(dst_rank, 2,energy_tmp);
                            cout<<"[MASTER] I receive energy_tmp status "<<endl;

                            tuple<int,int,int,int,int,int>  periodicity_now;

                            mpi_world.recv(dst_rank, 3,periodicity_now);
                            cout<<"[MASTER] I receive periodicity_now status "<<endl;




                        }

                        std::cout << "[MASTER] Rank " << dst_rank << " is done.\n"<<endl;
                        // Check if there is remaining jobs
                        if (job_id  < periodicity_vector.size()) {
                            // Tell the slave that a new job is coming.
                            stop = false;
                            mpi_world.isend(dst_rank, 0, stop);
                            // Send the new job.
                            //                            std::cout << "[MASTER] Sending new job (" << job_id
                            //                            << ") to SLAVE " << dst_rank << ".\n"<<endl;
                            mpi_world.isend(dst_rank, 0, job_id);
                            mpi_world.isend(dst_rank, 1, min_bound);

                            reqs[dst_rank] = mpi_world.irecv(dst_rank, 0,status_of_slave[dst_rank]);
                            ++job_id;
                        }
                        else {
                            // Send stop message to slave.
                            stop = true;
                            mpi_world.send(dst_rank, 0, stop);
                            killed_slave.insert(dst_rank);
                        }
                    }
                }
                usleep(1000);
            }
            std::cout << "[MASTER] Sent all jobs.\n";

            // Listen for the remaining jobs, and send stop messages on completion.
            bool all_done = false;
            while (!all_done) {
                all_done = true;
                for (unsigned int dst_rank = 1; dst_rank < mpi_world.size(); ++dst_rank) {

                    //                    cout<<"[MASTER] check if Slave "<<dst_rank<<" is killed?"<<endl;

                    if(killed_slave.count(dst_rank)==0)
                    {
                        //                        cout<<"[MASTER] Slave "<<dst_rank<<" is not yet killed"<<endl;
                        //
                        //                        cout<<"[MASTER] last round; checking status message from slave "<<dst_rank<<endl;

                        if (reqs[dst_rank].test()) {

                            cout<<"[MASTER] last round; checking status message from slave "<<dst_rank<<endl;
                            cout<<"status_of_slave["<<dst_rank<<"] is "<<status_of_slave[dst_rank] <<endl;


                            if(status_of_slave[dst_rank]=="finish") {
                                //note here, I deliberated exclude cluster_type_periodic which may be the culprit of a lot of bad computing performance for realistic system

                                cout<<"[MASTER] I receive finish status from slave "<<dst_rank<<endl;

                                //                            remember to receive more detail output;
                                //                            and update the things you want to update;
                                map<tuple<int,int,int,int>,int>  spin_tmp;
                                double energy_tmp=0;
                                mpi_world.recv(dst_rank, 1,spin_tmp);
                                cout<<"[MASTER] I receive spin_tmp status "<<endl;

                                mpi_world.recv(dst_rank, 2,energy_tmp);
                                cout<<"[MASTER] I receive energy_tmp status "<<endl;

                                tuple<int,int,int,int,int,int>  periodicity_now;

                                mpi_world.recv(dst_rank, 3,periodicity_now);
                                cout<<"[MASTER] I receive periodicity_now status "<<endl;



                                spin_periodic[periodicity_now]=spin_tmp;
                                energy_periodic[periodicity_now]=energy_tmp;

                                cout<<"[MASTER] I updated spin_periodic and energy_periodic "<<endl;


                                {
                                    double dump1;
                                    findminmax(energy_periodic, min_bound, dump1);
                                    matchnumber(energy_periodic, min_bound, min_list);

                                    if (very_verbose){
                                        cout << "\nUB: " << min_bound << ", LB: " << lowerbound_from_compat << "; Periodicity: ";
                                        printvector(min_list);
                                        cout << endl;
                                    }

                                    if (min_bound <= lowerbound_from_compat+1e-5*max_value_of_J) {
                                        done=true;
                                    }

                                }

                                cout<<"[MASTER] I updated minlist and minbound "<<endl;


                            }
                            // Tell the slave that it can exit.
                            bool stop = true;
                            mpi_world.send(dst_rank, 0, stop);
                            killed_slave.insert(dst_rank);
                            cout<<"[MASTER] I stopped slave "<<dst_rank<<endl;

                        }
                        else {
                            all_done = false;
                        }
                    }


                }
                usleep(1000);
            }
            std::cout << "[MASTER] Handled all jobs, killed every process.\n";
        }



    }
}
```

The logic of the code shall have no issue, since it runs completely fine on my Mac with 16 cores... However, mysterious segmentation fault happens when I run it on Stampede super computer (sometimes even with as low as 8 cores)... This is very mysterious...

Comment: It's impossible from the outside to debug your code based on two lines. There is certainly a parallel debugger installed on stampede. Go ahead - use it. You could also post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here.

Comment: I edited and provided a minimal version of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think basically this is impossible to debug... Because I try the same program on Nersc, running on 240 cores without any issue....